# Switch case menus and terminal windows in C

Tags: c, menu, switch-statement

For some class project I had to write an app in C that revolves around a `switch/case` menu that loops forever. The project is done, but I have one question remaining:

Everytime the menu loops, it is displayed under any previous prints in the terminal.

Is there a way such that the menu is being displayed in one terminal window, and the consequences of a choice in the menu is being displayed in another window?

Ideally, I would like to have one menu window and one "program" window.

I hope this makes sense,

Thank you very much.

EDIT : the app should be functional on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: This is possible but not easy.

Comment: use a library like libtk to manage multiple windows in a C program.

Comment: I think your problem is more easily solved by displaying the menu in the upper part of the terminal and using the lower lines for the output. But both solutions are very platform specific, so please add some requirements about that.